# Is there any way to keep another app from displaying picture in picture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have an app which shows aggregated video metadata from multiple networks (amazon, netflix, etc.) which allows a user to launch a video in its respective app using iOS url schemes. There is a UX problem when a user is watching a video in Amazon Instant, then opens my open using iPad slide out and chooses a different source. Amazon’s video player animates to PIP and netflix is played full screen. I would like to restrict PIP when a new full screen video is being launched.

I’ve tried things like hi-jacking the audio session and playing a video in my own app right before launching the URL in an attempt to stop it, but this seems to only work when starting w/ Netflix and launching an Amazon link, not the inverse. Any ideas on how to restrict an app from starting?

[image]

Comment: Typically, questions about "Can I keep someone else's app from doing X" are going to have the same answer. "No."

Comment: While typically I would agree with you, that is not always the case. Eg. Can I restrict another app's audio from playing over mine? "Yes." I'm looking for ideas around it, rather than accepting an assumption.

Comment: why is it an UX problem? maybe users want to do exactly this.

Comment: @vikingosegundo company hierarchy ;) although, not having a clean way of doing this will probably be enough of a counter argument

Comment: I see. Once a former boss of mine was raving about some iOS given thing. he told me to call Apple and tell them to change it… not much later I changed the company. Now I work in a [holacratic](http://www.holacracy.org) company. No more stupid orders.